# How to use Bezier curve interpolation?

Tags: rust, bezier, spline

I want to interpolate values between multiple points with Bezier curve interpolation using the [splines](https://github.com/phaazon/splines) crate.

My current implementation looks like this:

```rs
let mut output_buffer: Vec<f32> = vec![ 0.0; buffer.len() ];

let mut points: Vec<Key<f32, f32>> = Vec::new();
for val in pos_index.iter() {
    let x = val.0;
    let y = val.1;
    points.push(Key::new(x, y, Interpolation::Bezier( 0.5 )));
}

let spline = Spline::from_vec(points);

for i in 0..output_buffer.len() {
    let v = spline.clamped_sample(i as f32).unwrap_or(0.0);
    output_buffer[i] = v;
}

output_buffer
```

But I do not known what value to put into `Interpolation::Bezier( 'value' )`.

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/splines/4.0.3/splines/interpolation/enum.Interpolation.html) does not help me neither and I cannot find any examples that use Bezier interpolation.

One important thing to note is that the points or keys are not evenly spaced out, so the distance between them is much higher on the first values that are closer to zero.

Comment: It's an open source package: if you can't find what you need in the docs, did you remember to write an issue so that author is aware of the fact that there is information missing? Because getting the documentation updated will help _far_ more people than a question on stackoverflow will =)

Comment: I'm guessing `V` is the tangent for the current point, but the docs could be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

At line [#170](https://github.com/phaazon/splines/blob/master/src/spline.rs#L170) of spline.rs, it shows V's values of `Interpolation::Bezier(V)` of cp0 (cp stands for control point) and cp1 are passed to the function `V::cubic_bezier` as the third and fourth parameters.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.rs/splines/4.0.3/splines/interpolate/trait.Interpolate.html#tymethod.cubic_bezier) of the function `cubic_bezier`.

> fn cubic_bezier(t: T, a: Self, **u**: Self, **v**: Self, b: Self) -> Self
>
> Cubic Bézier interpolation.
>
> a is the first point; b is the second point; **u is the output tangent of a to the curve and v is the input tangent of b to the curve.**

We can see *u* and *v* stand for tangents and also, from the function signature, we can see their type is `Self`, the type that implements the `Interpolate` trait. The section [Implementations on Foreign Types](https://docs.rs/splines/4.0.3/splines/interpolate/trait.Interpolate.html#foreign-impls) of Interpolate documentation lists the types that implements the trait. Here are some as examples:

```
impl Interpolate<f32> for Vector1<f32>
impl Interpolate<f32> for Vector2<f32>
impl Interpolate<f64> for Vector1<f64>
impl Interpolate<f64> for Vector2<f64>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It can't be the tension since the tension is always a floating-point value, whereas the parameter for `Interpolation::Bezier` has the same type as the value you're interpolating.

Comment: @Jmb thanks for pointing out the incorrectness of my previous answer. I have edited with my new findings.